# Test fails only if being ran individually

Tags: reactjs, react-testing-library

I have a CRA app in which I have this test:

```
  test('renders component with errors', () => {
    const mockedResData = {
      headers: {},
      status: 404,
    };
    const mockedPathoginicityResponse = {
      headers: {},
      status: 404,
    };

    getData.mockImplementation(() => ({
      setOptions: () => ({
        signal: AbortSignal,
        call: () => Promise.reject(mockedData),
      }),
    }));

    getNestedData.mockImplementation(() => ({
      setOptions: () => ({
        signal: AbortSignal,
        call: () => Promise.reject(mockedNestedData),
      }),
    }));

    const { container } = render(<Panels />);

    expect(getData).toBeCalled();
    expect(getNestedData).toBeCalled();
    expect(container).toMatchSnapshot();
  });
```

For clarity, this is the simplified version of `<Panels>`.

```
export default function Panels() {

  useEffect(() => {

    const controller = new AbortController();

    getData({ q: query })
      .setOptions({ signal: controller.signal })
      .call()
      .then(({ response }) => {

        if (response.length > 0) {
          getNestedData({ ...nestedQuery })
            .setOptions({ signal: controller.signal })
            .call()
            .then(res) => {
                // stuff
            })
            .catch(err => {
                setError(err.status);
            });
        } else {
          setLoading(false);
        }
      })
      .catch(err => {
        setError(err.status);
      });
    return () => {
      controller.abort();
    };
  }, [data]);

  return (
    <p>{content}</p>
  );
}
```

This test should obviously fail on `expect(getNestedData).toBeCalled();` as it is never called. Still, if I run all the tests with `react-scripts test` this test succeeds. If I run the test individually it fails.
Before thinking about an easy pollution between different runs, note that this is the last `test` of the file, and if I run the whole set of tests of the module (file) it still fails.

Comment: have you tried adding `beforeEach(()=>{clearAllMocks()})`, just to make sure the mock hasn't been called in another test? You could also change  toBeCalled() into toHaveBeenCalledWith() or toHaveBeenCalledWith() to see how often and with what args the mock has been called. maybe that gives you a hint.